# Message Processing from DLQ ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.5.1 broker and want to generate a report from DLQ. Please advise if i can achieve this from admin console or should be programmatic.

Comment: I have to create html report of all the error details.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ admin console provides a feature to view report in XML format and also provides graphical view for it.

If you only want it in HTML format you will need to do it programmaticaly.